# How to identify and remove the SQL table row which contains UTF 8 BOM characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, utf-8

I recently identified that some of the rows in our table contains UTF 8 BOM (Byte Order Marking) characters (ï»¿).. Is there a way to identify those rows and removing the BOM characters from those rows?

Answer (score 3):

Balu, the answer you posted will truncate the value to 30 characters because the no length was specified for the `CAST` and `CONVERT` declarations of the `varchar` and `nvarchar` data types.

Consider using STUFF instead:

```
--nvarchar example
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET UnicodeColumn = STUFF(UnicodeColumn, 1, 1, '')
WHERE CAST(LEFT(UnicodeColumn, 1) AS binary(2)) IN(0xFFFE, 0xFEFF);

--varchar example
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET NonUnicodeColumn = STUFF(NonUnicodeColumn, 1, 2, '')
WHERE CAST(LEFT(NonUnicodeColumn, 2) AS binary(2)) IN(0xFFFE, 0xFEFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got it:

```
select *, SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(stringValue AS varchar) AS nvarchar), 2, LEN(stringValue))
from test_table
where fileNumber=102 and CAST(left(stringValue,1) AS varchar)='?';

update test_table
set stringValue=SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(stringValue AS varchar) AS nvarchar), 2, LEN(stringValue))
where fileNumber=102 and CAST(left(stringValue,1) AS varchar)='?';
```

Comment: [Please don't cast as varchar/nvarchar without specifying length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).